# How do I completely exhaust the items in this array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, break

I am trying to write a program that asks the user for a number to search in the array. If the array contains the given number, the program tells the index containing the number. If the array doesn't contain the given number, the program will advise that the number wasn't found.

My problem is probably a formatting issue. Here's my program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] array = new int[8];

    array[0] = 6;
    array[1] = 2;
    array[2] = 8;
    array[3] = 1;
    array[4] = 3;
    array[5] = 0;
    array[6] = 9;
    array[7] = 7;

    System.out.print("Search for? ");
    int searching = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());

    for (int i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
        
        if (array[i] == searching) {
            System.out.println(searching + " is at index " + i + ".");
            break;
        }
        if (i == array.length-1 && searching != array[i]) {
                System.out.println(searching +" was not found.");
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

I don't like how I have to add the 'break;' statement after the program finds the index of the searched integer. This doesn't allow the program to find multiple outcomes. Say searching = 3 and 3 was at the index of 4 AND 5. The way I have the program written will not allow the program to find the second index that fulfills the premise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find all the indexes of a given number in the array, you need to iterate over the array completely. You can't use a `break` statement to stop the iteration.

You could put all the indexes of a given number in a `List`. To check if number exists atleast once in the array, check the size of the `List` after loop has ended.

```
List<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
     if (array[i] == searching) {
         indexList.add(i);
     }
}

if (indexList.size() == 0) {
    System.out.println(searching +" was not found.");
} else {
    // iterate over indexList and print all the indexes
}
```

Alternatively, you could use some flag variable to check if number was found at-least once or not and this check should be outside the loop.

```
boolean exists = false;

for (int i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
     if (array[i] == searching) {
         exists = true;
         System.out.println(searching + " is at index " + i + ".");
     }
}

if (!exists) {
    System.out.println(searching +" was not found.");
}
```

Comment: This is a beautiful answer. I figured there was some tool to use in java that I either don't know yet or am not used to using. That flag technique was definitely it. Thank you. I didn't know i could use it that way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is add a boolean variable that tells you if the value has been found. Initially it's false, but you update it to `true` when you find a matching value.

```
boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
    
    if (array[i] == searching) {
        System.out.println(searching + " is at index " + i + ".");
        found = true;
    }
}
```

After the loop, you check if a value was found:

```
if (!found) {
    System.out.println(searching +" was not found.");         
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this is so simple and clean.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a boolean flag `found` assign it to be `true` if found (at least once)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] array = new int[8];

        array[0] = 6;
        array[1] = 2;
        array[2] = 8;
        array[3] = 1;
        array[4] = 3;
        array[5] = 3;
        array[6] = 9;
        array[7] = 7;

        System.out.print("Search for? ");
        int searching = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {

            if (array[i] == searching) {
                System.out.println(searching + " is at index " + i + ".");
                found = true;
            }

        }
        if (!found)
        {
            System.out.println(searching +" was not found.");
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Search for? 3
3 is at index 4.
3 is at index 5.

Search for? 10
10 was not found.
```